# Why is random forest performing worse than decision tree

Tags: r, classification, data-mining, random-forest, decision-tree

I have a data set with 1962 observations and 46 columns. Column 46 is the target. 6 of the other columns are nominal variables and the rest are ordinal variables. I have preprocessed them using as follows:

```
for (i in c(1:4,6,9,46)){
    cw_alldata_known[,i] <- as.factor(cw_alldata_known[,i])
}

for (i in c(5,7,8,10:45)){
  cw_alldata_known[,i] <- as.ordered(cw_alldata_known[,i])
}
```

Then I divide them 50/50 into training and test sets.
I fitted a decision tree using `party` package of R:

```
cw.ctree <- ctree(cr~.,data = cw.train)
```

Then I also fitted a random forest model:

```
cw.forest <- randomForest(credit.rating ~ ., data=cw.train,ntree=107)
```

I have tried other `ntree` values but 107 seems to be the best.
The accuracy on the test set of decision tree is around 61%, while random forest is only 56%. I read that random forest is often more robust and reliable. Why doesn't it perform better than decision tree in this case?

Comment: maybe this is a question for the crossvalidated board...

Comment: you can copy paste the question over there

Comment: Questions about the performance of certain statistical models aren't really specific programming questions so they are not a good fit for Stack Overflow. You are more likely to get help at [stats.se] where questions about statistical models are on topic.

Comment: Because "often more robust" is not the same as "always better". In particular, whrn you have little data for too many variables.